# Enable SQLCMD mode in Azure Data Studio

Tags: sqlcmd, azure-data-studio

Is there any way to set SQLCMD mode in Azure Data Studio?  I'm currently running 1.46.1.

The [Azure Data Studio - Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/what-is-azure-data-studio#query-editor) page in MS Learn shows that Azure Data Studio supports SQLCMD in the Query Editor.  However, I cannot see any way to enable SQLCMD mode, any menu item or button that would do it.  I did see an [old blog post from September 2019](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/09/10/the-september-release-of-azure-data-studio-is-now-available/#:%7E:text=SQLCMD%20mode%20allows%20users%20to,can%20now%20output%20SQLCMD%20scripts.) which showed a button to the right of the Database dropdown at the top of the Query Editor.  However, I cannot see that button in my version of Azure Data Studio (it's seemingly been replaced by the Estimated Plan and Enable Actual Plan buttons).  I also cannot find any Keyboard Shortcuts or Extensions related to SQLCMD.

**EDIT:**
These are the buttons I see at the top of the Query Editor window:
[image: buttons visible at top of Query Editor window]

They're different from those in @ThomA's screenshot in the comments.  As far as I can see, though, there isn't an obvious option to enable the SQMCMD mode button.

Comment: Do you *not* have an [Enable SQLCMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN7Aa.png) button?

Comment: @ThomA: Edited the question to include a screenshot of the Query Editor buttons I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it: I needed to enable preview features.  The SQLCMD release announcement was over 3 years ago so it never occurred to me SQLCMD would still be in preview 3 years later.

To enable preview features:

1. Press `Ctrl+,` to bring up the Settings;
2. In the settings search box enter `enable unreleased`.  ADS should display one result: `Enable unreleased preview features`;
3. Tick the `Enable unreleased preview features` checkbox.

If you go back to the Query Editor you should now see the `Enable SQLCMD` button:

[image: "Enable SQLCMD" button visible in Query Editor]